# Hide/unhide rows based on checkbox on Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet which has checkboxes in column P, as and when a checkbox is ticked the corresponding row automatically hides.

I am looking to add an additional check box in G1 that will show all hidden rows if checked and if possible a checkbox in E1 to then hide again all the rows that have the checkbox ticked in column P.

Basically I want to automatically hide rows when I tick the checkbox in column P
Then later I may need to review the hidden rows by clicking the checkbox in G1.
When I am finished reviewing the hidden rows above click a checkbox in E1 and all rows which are checked in column P will hide again.

```
function onEdit(e){ 
    if (e.range.columnStart != 16 || e.value != "TRUE") return;
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().hideRows(e.range.rowStart); 
}
```

Comment: Please add what you've already tried. You can start by including your `code` so we can help you better on debugging it.

Comment: Please write the question accordingly to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Firstly it will be great a better description of the code and a demo/example of the code.

Comment: Hi jpneey, I am a beginner to scripts and the below is what I have and works when column P is ticked.  I am not sure how to proceed with the script for showing all hidden rows and rehiding the checked rows.                                                                                               function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart != 16 || e.value != "TRUE") return;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().hideRows(e.range.rowStart);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

- Check if edited cell is `G1` via [getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation). In that case, check if value is `TRUE`, and if that's the case, show all rows. An easy option to show all rows is using [unhideRow(row)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#unhiderowrow), setting `A:A` as your range (since this includes all rows in the sheet).
- Check if edited cell is `E1`. If the value is `TRUE`, retrieve all values from `P` column via [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues), iterate through them, and hide the corresponding rows if the value is `true`, using [hideRows(rowIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideRows(Integer)).
- Check if the edited cell is in column `P`, and use `hideRows` on the edited row if that's the case, as you're already doing.

#### Code snippet:

```
function onEdit(e){
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = e.range;
  const editedValue = e.value;
  if (range.getA1Notation() === "G1" && editedValue === "TRUE") {
    sheet.unhideRow(sheet.getRange("A:A"));
  } else if (range.getA1Notation() === "E1" && editedValue === "TRUE") {
    const firstRow = 2;
    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    const pValues = sheet.getRange("P" + firstRow + ":P" + lastRow).getValues().flat();
    pValues.forEach((pValue,i) => {
      if (pValue === true) {
        sheet.hideRows(i + firstRow);
      }
    });
  } else if (e.range.columnStart === 16 && editedValue === "TRUE") {
    sheet.hideRows(range.rowStart); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lamblichus, wow thanks for the help and solution which has worked to how I had visioned. Thanks again for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit of an old thread, but still very helpfull to al lot of people i guess. Both the code from the TS and the answer were very helpfull.

I used this for a similar project and found it a bit strange to have two checkboxes to show/hide rows though, so i made this work with one checkbox in cell "G1" to toggle the view hide/unhide.

**Code Snippet**

```js
function onEdit(e){
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = e.range;
  const editedValue = e.value;
  if (range.getA1Notation() === "G1" && editedValue === "TRUE") {
    sheet.unhideRow(sheet.getRange("A:A"));
  } else if (range.getA1Notation() === "G1" && editedValue === "FALSE") {
    const firstRow = 2;
    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    const pValues = sheet.getRange("P" + firstRow + ":P" + lastRow).getValues().flat();
    pValues.forEach((pValue,i) => {
      if (pValue === true) {
        sheet.hideRows(i + firstRow);
      }
    });
  } else if (e.range.columnStart === 16 && editedValue === "TRUE") {
    sheet.hideRows(range.rowStart); 
  }
}
```